# Stack Overflow for Teams - Microsoft Teams Integration Log In error

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

We've been trying out Microsoft Teams for online collaboration, and we are having some difficulties getting the integration with Stack Overflow for Teams working. My colleague originally set it up, but I am now trying to help figure out why it is not working ... quite unsuccessfully I might add.

On the SO side, it shows that there is an integration with Microsoft Teams.
On Microsoft Teams, it keeps asking me to log in. As per [this article](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000192011-microsoft-teams-integration-overview) I click the Log In button and it asks me to "Authorize" some stuff. I do that, then it takes me to another page, saying it is already installed. I close the window, and back to square one, where it keeps telling me to log in. I am the second person to be trying to figure this out.

Yes, I have tried installing and uninstalling just about everything that I could, sign in and out, restart computer, and so on.

Anyone else encounter this and know what to do?

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]